# Why was my question closed?

Tags: discussion

[E: Type 'echo' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1450423/e-type-echo-is-not-known-on-line-1-in-source-list-etc-apt-sources-list-d-vir)

The post that was sited as the reason for closing my question, does nothing to help me if I can't comment on it to ask how to fix my problem!

Comment: You [said](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1450423/e-type-echo-is-not-known-on-line-1-in-source-list-etc-apt-sources-list-d-vir#comment2532637_1450423) you are using Linux Mint, which is not supported on this site. This site is for Ubuntu and its official flavors. https://ubuntu.com/desktop/flavours

Comment: Your error message tells you the problem, in the file mentioned in the message on line 1, there is an invalid "echo" command (it's unknown, not being a valid entry in that file of sources).  That needs correction.  Being able to comment on the question won't help you, you need to correct the line (if you'd pasted the line in your first question, we could have provided more detail, but with only the message - we can only tell you what it means; where it tells you the file with the error & line number with first error). Comment it out, remove it, or correct it - your only choices.

Comment: PPAs are a Ubuntu tool; your file mixes up Debian & Ubuntu (different OSes), but if using Linux Mint based on Debian, you're only asking for trouble mixing up sources  (Debian & Ubuntu never align, even if *testing* & *development* are used; they never really align, but released products are further apart!).  Either way Linux Mint isn't Ubuntu (nor *flavor* of Ubuntu) and thus off-topic on this site.

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Linux Mint forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu is its many support options, you opted for Linux Mint so take advantage of its support options, or SE Unix & Linux*)

Comment: FYI:  Your question was closed as *duplicate*, but if you also look the only alternative was you were off-topic, being outside of site rules anyway.  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: A source on my current box contains this `deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm main contrib non-free` .... ie. I'm currently using Debian; but if I was using Ubuntu; the URL won't match, my release (bookworm) won't match, and *contrib* & *non-free* won't match.  Only the *main* will match Ubuntu.  Linux Mint has products based on Debian, and products based on Ubuntu; both of which are off-topic on this site as not Ubuntu systems.  You must match the Linux Mint you're using (ie. either Debian based, OR Ubuntu based, they are **not** the same but your source mixed the two; PPAs are Ubuntu)

Comment: guiverc
"Being able to comment on the question won't help you, you need to correct the line (if you'd pasted the line in your first question, we could have provided more detail, but with only the message - we can only tell you what it means; where it tells you the file with the error & line number with first error). Comment it out, remove it, or correct it - your only choices."
As I tried to tell you. If I had been able to comment on that post, none of this would have happened.

Comment: guiverc I could have just asked in a comment, how to edit nano and this would have been over with. The only thing I did wrong through any of this was to copy code from the incorrect information and post in the wrong forums to ask how to correct the problem. This got so completely out of hand and blown out of proportion, it's unreal.

Comment: @user_OU812 This question and answer has generated an inordinate number of flags. I would suggest 2 things: 1. Have a look at the Ubuntu Code of Conduct: https://askubuntu.com/conduct and allow this document to guide future posts. 2. You have been given 2 answers by long term AU users: profit by their words and then move on.

Comment: andrew.46 The inordinate number of flags were because of bigoted responses and accusations, of which I pointed out correctly in comments that somebody deleted. I have been accused of things I did not say or do, quite a few times. If this had not been allowed, this issue would not have dragged on like it did. People even kept this going after I thanked the people for both answers, as if I were still asking about the same subject.

Comment: @user_OU812  You *appear* to keep operating under the assumption this is a forum, but it's not.  This is a Question & Answer (Q&A) site, which operates different to a Forum. https://ubuntuforums.org/ is the Ubuntu Forum(s) which has an area where Linux Mint is on-topic.  Once you realize the difference between a Q&A site, and a Forum, you'll hopefully better understand what has happened here.  My 2c anyway.

Answer (score 9):

**Firstly** your question was off-topic.

If you read https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic you'll note this site is for Ubuntu and [*flavors* of Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours), with Linux Mint specifically mentioned in the questions to be avoided (as off-topic).

**Secondly** your question was a *duplicate*.

The directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` is empty on a new install (*of on-topic Ubuntu systems*), so anything in that file was added by a user with `sudo` privileges.

Your error told you line 1 of the file mentioned in the error message contained error(s), ie. `echo` is not a valid *keyword* used in sources files.  That file needed to be edited & corrected to match your system.

Linux Mint provides system(s) based on Ubuntu, and system(s) based on Debian, your picture of a file contained a mixture of both Debian & Ubuntu - thus was invalid even if the *echo* was ignored. Your question however was off-topic on this site, which deals only with Ubuntu  (*Debian isn't on-topic, unless the question is specific to how Ubuntu & Debian interact, as both teams often do*).

*Don't forget this site is an official Ubuntu support site; I can access it using only my Ubuntu SSO/signon, though I can't access CHAT services as they require a Stack Exchange signon.  You're likely accessing it via Stack Exchange, where 'SE Unix & Linux' covers your Operating System, not this Ubuntu only site.*

Comment: If you had looked at any part of my question, I was not able to use the "duplicate" question, because, as I said several times, I can not comment on that question because I don't have enough points, so I can't ask questions about how to correct my problem. Yes it was added with sudo, I added it. Obviously I added it from the incorrect information / repository, or whatever you want to call it.

Comment: I'm new at using any Linux so I didn't know it was incorrect, when I copied and pasted the lines in to the terminal to add it. I Googled the error that I got, and this was the first website that came up and was an exact match, or I would not have asked the question here.

Comment: I suggest you read site rules before using a site. If you looked those rules, it would have told you your question would have been closed due to off-topic; instead the *duplicate* reason was used as the reason for closure.  You're welcome to use this site as for *reading details* regardless of your OS (eg. I'm using Debian currently thus cannot, but even if I was using my Ubuntu *lunar* system I couldn't ask questions here as *lunar* isn't a released product until April when it becomes Lubuntu 23.04) but you can only ask questions when on-topic for the site.

Comment: There was no reason for you to *comment* on the other question, as I can't see how you could have provided any additional help for the question/answer already existing; plus your system being off-topic on this site meant any detail you had would have been incorrect.  I suggest you ask on a site where your OS is known, and be clear as to what product you're using, ie. LMDE? or LMUE (*LM Debian edition* or *LM Ubuntu editions* of Linux Mint!) as they differ; your details mix-matched details from each - where you cannot if you want it to work; computers require letter-perfect details.

Comment: FYI:   Google is only a machine, and often gives *misleading* or *incomplete* results.. I'm a Lubuntu team member, and dislike how google can give *legitimate*, *fan* or *fake* web sites for downloading Lubuntu... but it's a machine, and the answers it gives depends on terms used in the search, language used in search etc... (you'll get correct details if certain keywords are used for some languages, but not all), so if using google - evaluate what you're given & ensure it's accurate before you trust it!   Google is **not** smart !

Answer (score 6):

It's common for folks who do not understand an answer to understandably complain that an answer is not helpful...or to mistakenly claim that an answer is not applicable or not duplicate.

Keep in mind that we are a community of volunteers. Few here are professional documentation writers or professional support engineers, and there is no training for these volunteers. We rely on YOU to help improve answers for future readers.

Please help improve answers by using the editing tools.

Or offer your own clearer, more accurate, better-written answer after you solve the problem.